# Is it possible to run Bash Commands in Apache Spark with Azure Synapse with Magic Commands

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

In databricks there is the following magic command $sh, that allows you run bash commands in a notebook.
For example if I wanted to run the following code in Databrick:

```
pip install great_expectations
```

I would issue the following code:

```
%sh
pip install great_expectations
```

Can someone let me know what the equivalent is with Apache Spark notebook in Azure Synapse?
It may well be that it isn't possible with Azure Synapse but I don't know.

Just to add to this question, in Databricks when I run the following command

```
great_expectations init
```

The command remains stuck in running, see image

[image]

However, what I would expect from a regular Linux OS when I run the same code would be

```
OK to proceed? [Y/n]:
```

Is there something I could add to

```
great_expectations init
```

To make the code return

```
OK to proceed? [Y/n]:
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Profile Spark data? `%sh` isn't designed for "interactive commands"

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I would like to install a python package called great_expectations. On Databricks I would simply enter the code %sh pip install great_expectations, but I don't have that option with Synapse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install packages just run a pip install preceded with a ! right in the synapse notebook like this.

`!pip install great_expectations`

I am also able to run shell commands in the notebook using this:  %%sh   for example

```
%%sh
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 2):

> Azure Synapse Analytics Spark pool supports - Only following magic commands are supported in Synapse pipeline : `%%pyspark`, `%%spark`, `%%csharp`, `%%sql`.

Python packages can be installed from repositories like PyPI and Conda-Forge by providing an environment specification file.

> Steps to install python package in Synapse Spark pool.

**Step1:** Get the packages details like **name** & **version** from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/great-expectations/#history)

**Note:** (great_expectations) and (0.13.19)

[image]

**Step2:** Create a `requirements.txt` file using the above name and version.

[image]

**Step3:** Upload the package to the Synapse Spark Pool.

[image]

**Step4:** Save and wait for applying packages settings in Synapse Spark pools.

[image]

**Step5:** Verify installed libraries

To verify if the correct versions of the correct libraries are installed from PyPI, run the following code:

```
import pkg_resources
for d in pkg_resources.working_set:
     print(d)
```

[image]

For more details, refer to [Manage Python libraries for Apache Spark in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-python-packages#verify-installed-libraries).

Comment: Is there *any* way to run shell commands?  o/w why don't i just stay on DataBricks ..

Comment: there is a way to run shell commands use `%%sh` as mentioned in my answer @WestCoastProjects